# How to use two color in one TCPDF Cell?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have an invoice template. i used Cell for showing text into box.

here is my code:

```
$ntitle = 'No:';
$factornum = '1898';
$startheader = 15;
$pdf->SetXY($startheader, 4);
$pdf->Cell(50, 0, 'Date: '.date("Y-m-d"), 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);
$pdf->SetXY($startheader, 12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->Cell(50, 0,  $ntitle . $factornum, 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
```

I want to use two text color in second cell.
$ntitle should be echo in black and $factornum in red

For example, output must be like:

No: (with black color) 1898 (with red color)

How can I do this in TCPDF?

I checked TCPDF examples. but I did not get any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ntitle = 'No:';
$factornum = '1898';
$startheader = 15;
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetXY($startheader, 4);
$pdf->Cell(50, 0, 'Date: '.date("Y-m-d"), 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);
$pdf->SetXY($startheader, 12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
//$pdf->Cell(50, 0,  $ntitle . $factornum, 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(50, '', '', '', '<span style="color:#000">'.$ntitle.'</span>' . $factornum, 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
```